# Sidekiq can't connect to redis in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have my redis server installed and running, but when I connect sidekiq using `bundle exec sidekiq` it throws an error message

> Timed out connecting to Redis on localhost:6379

Redis Server is running on port: 6379.

Comment: Is redis running on 6379 port? Run ```netstat -nlp | grep redis``` command

Comment: yup redis is running on 6379. The command you provided throws an error, `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using bundle exec sidekiq?

Try connecting with "redis-cli -h localhost"

Comment: Throws an error, `Could not connect to Redis at localhost:6379: Connection refused`

Comment: Also try connecting with redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 - if this works make sure you edit the redis file so it listens on the correct interfaces!

Answer (score 0):

I think it means you're redis server isn't running. 
Try running `sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start` on your terminal, also make sure redis has permission to write to /var/log/redis.log or it won't start.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue was my redis production url wasn't correct.

My fix was:

1. open `$ sudo nano gitlab/htdocs/config/resque.yml`
2. change `production: redis://some-wrong-url:6379` to `production: redis://localhost:6379`
3. restarted my Bitnami stack `$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`

I first verified my redis url from the answer @henley left.

*Note I'm using a Bitnami stack